# JavaScript - Class definition best practice

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, oop

I'm quite new in Node.js (and Javascript in general) programming and I have a huge doubt.
I would like to restyle some code I've written in order to fit the OOP style, so I need to define some classes: but how should I do that?

I've read the [Mozilla introduction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript) and it seems like I should use "prototype" when defining new methods inside a class:

```
myClass.prototype.myFunction = function() { ... }
```

but in many JavaScript projects (for example on Github) I noticed a different way of defining functions, by using something like

```
self.myFunction = function () { ... }
```

So, which one is the style you suggest? And what differences there are between them?

Thank you very much for your help! :)